# What I'll need to implement for real robot instead of using gazebo plugin?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For moving robot in simulated world I'm using differential_drive_controller gazebo plugin, but I wonder what it'll be needed to implement for real custom robot for moving it in real world.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226033/what-i%27ll-need-to-implement-for-real-robot-instead-of-using-gazebo-plugin?/) by [vovka](https://answers.ros.org/users/25858/vovka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Gazebo plugin takes in the Twist message and turns it into a virtual left motor and right motor command to make the simulated robot move in the simulation.

Your real robot code will need to take in the Twist message and turn it into a real left motor and right motor command to make the real robot move. The details of that really depends on your robot hardware.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vovka](https://answers.ros.org/users/25858/vovka/) on 2016-02-19**:
@Kurt Leucht, thanks for your response. Do you know where I can see some examples of it?

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2016-02-19**:
How to command motors completely depends on your hardware.  What is your hardware?  How do you intend to send commands to your motors? What is the hardware device that you need to send commands to?